# VS-2013 error message after installation: The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2013. After installation I get the message:

"The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported."

Comment: Could you show the code where the error occurs? Without any code, it's impossible to tell where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

With google I found an entry in the Microsoft forums:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33dfdba4-4a11-4895-9554-0b2fd29e2578/visual-studio-2013-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-no-such-interface-supported?forum=vssetup

> Try re-registering the actxprxy.dll and oleaut32.dll file in the %SystemRoot%\system32 directory.